# Problem on homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having a difficult time with this qualifying exam problem.  The problem is easy for the case $n = 2$.  However, I do not see how to solve generalize it, and I suspect there is another approach to be taken in the general case.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $P \subset S^n$ be a finite set in the sphere of dimension $n \geq 2.$
Prove that $S^n \backslash P$ is homotopy equivalent to a closed manifold if and
only if $P$ contains at most 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

If $|P| = 1 + k$ then $S^n \setminus P$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $k$ copies of $S^{n-1}$, and for $k \ge 2$ we want to show that this doesn't have the homotopy type of a closed manifold. The top cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ of any closed manifold is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but this is not true here: the top cohomology is $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^k$ by Mayer-Vietoris.